# How to store/match multiple dates per Entity in Google Datastore / GQL?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have entities representing people in Google Datastore. Each person has periods (from date/time, to date/time) they are available for jobs. I want to be able to search to see which people are available on a specific date. Just wondering how to model this and construct the GQL query(s).

Obviously there is the datetime property in Datastore, but each person will have multiple dates and times they are available and I don't know in advance how many. So I could store dates and times in a StringList in some sort of datetime syntax but I'm assuming I can't run an "intelligent" date/time query on this (e.g. is my search date within one of the periods specified in that property).

So I can only think to extract people from Datastore (who match against other criteria, e.g. a geospatial query) and then parse the 'periods' StringList for each person entity in my code to work out who is actually available on my search date/time. Or is there a better, more automated way?

I think my questions are non-language specific, but I'm using PHP running on Google App Engine and the great [php-gds](https://github.com/tomwalder/php-gds) library to access DataStore.

Many thanks for any suggestions or help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new entity called something like "AvailablePeriod". You can make it a child entity of a User entity. Make end date indexed. You can create as many such entities for one user entity as necessary.

Now you can easily query all periods for a specific user that have not ended yet.

Comment: Thanks, this sounds good. I'm not clear on how to create a child entity or how it works exactly but guess I can google that :) But with your suggestion, would it be possible to construct a query which matched against properties of the user and against the available periods? If so, what might that look like in GQL? Thanks

Comment: You can use ancestor query to find all periods for a user, or you can query all periods to find all available periods and then get a user ID from the parent key of the entity.

Comment: Thanks very much for the tips. Is there a way to match against several properties for the parent entities and also match against the AvailablePeriod child entities, all in one query? I'm thinking something along the lines of this: (to follow)

Comment: "SELECT * FROM People WHERE isprovider = true AND personjobtype = @ jobtypes AND personsex = @ sex AND personrating >= @ rating" AND persondatetime ( is in AvailablePeriods for that person ), ['jobtypes' => $searchvalues->jobtypes, 'sex' => $searchvalues->sex, 'rating' => $searchvalues->rating]"

Comment: Every query works with one entity kind only. Also, personally, I try to avoid overly complex queries. Actually, many complex queries results in a series of queries "under the hood", so you get no performance benefits by putting everything into a single query.

Comment: Thanks Andrei. Just wondering how come you suggest matching just on the end date of a period (in your original answer). If I want to match a specific date/time against available periods would I not need to match start date also so that I knew the desired date and time fell within the available period and not just before the end of it? (thinking of many future periods). Thanks again.

Comment: In the Datastore you can only use one inequality filter on a property. I don't know if GQL works around this limitation under the hood.